# Retrieve custom fields linked to an contactEvent in a Decision Split

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

I have a question concerning /contactEvents route in Journey Builder.

I am firing a /contactEvents Event with some custom data (eventStatus field).

The Data extension used for the Event is called "Website_Event" and has the EventInstanceID, ParentEventInstanceID, ContactKey + my custom eventStatus field.

Here is the API call :

```
 var options = {
        uri: '/contacts/v1/contactEvents',
        retry: true,
        form: {
          "contactKey": "A001",
          "eventDefinitionKey": "ContactEvent-XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
          "data": [{
            "id": "Data_Extension_ID",
            "name": "Website_Event",
            "items": [{
              "values": [{
                "name": "eventStatus",
                "value": "isConnected"
              }]
            }]
          }]
        },
        json: true
    };
```

This call injects the contact "A001" in the journey that has the EVENT DEFINITION KEY = ContactEvent-XXXXXXXXXXXXX. This EVENT DEFINITION KEY is linked to a data extension (Let's call it Master Data Extension) that has a SubscriberKey, Firstname and Lastname fields.

When I want to configure my decision split, I find under the Event Data all the fields in the Master Data Extension. Under the Contact Event I find the "Website_Event" (which is the destination of the /contactEvents route) but I have no clue on how to make a decision split based on the EventStatus field because I cannot link the EventStatusID with the Subscriber in the Master Data Extension as the relationship between the Contact and the Event data extension is one to many.

I hope I am clear enough :) But tell me if you need more details.

Have a nice weekend,

Zak

**UPDATE**

Here is the new request I tried based on Eliot's answer.

```
var options = {
        uri: '/contacts/v1/contactEvents',
        retry: true,
        form: {
            "contactKey": req.body.contactKey,
            "eventDefinitionKey": "ContactEvent-XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "data": [{
                "name": "Website_Event",
                "items": [{
                    "values": [{
                        "name": "eventStatus",
                        "value": "isConnected"
                    }]
                }]
            },
            {
                "name": "Event_Status",
                "items": [{
                    "values": [{
                        "name": "ContactKey",
                        "value": req.body.contactKey
                    }, {
                        "name": "status",
                        "value": "isConnected"
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        },
        json: true
            // other request options
    };
```

Comment: I assume you mean "EventInstanceID and ParentEventInstanceID", not "EventStatusId and ParentEventStatusId". Please confirm and update your question for clarity. I believe I have a solution for you, but I'll need to test it first — give me a couple of days!

Comment: I modified your question to use "EventInstanceID, ParentEventInstanceID" instead of "EventStatusId, ParentEventStatusId" as I think this is what you meant to say!

Comment: Hi Eliot, 

Thank you so much.. Yes i meant "EventInstanceID and ParentEventInstanceID" you can blame friday afternoon... But next time I will be more careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some extensive troubleshooting with @zeljazouli over a webinar, I learned that it appears you can no longer include multiple Attribute Sets in your data array. We exhausted every possible permutation in testing this. This certainly used to work when I last tried (which was a couple of years ago), but something has definitely changed along the way.

So I came up with a different solution using [Data Binding](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm) in the Event Context which we have tested and this works:

1. Add a field named EventInstanceID to your Event Source DE
2. Add a Update Contact Data Event to your Journey
3. Configure the Update Contact Data Event to update Event Source DE field created in step 1 using the value `{{Event.Event-Contact-Key-Here.EventInstanceID}}`, where '`Event-Contact-Key-Here`' is the Event Definition Key of your Event (e.g. `ContactEvent-ef18905a-b7c5-d66b-3ca5-d1e939dc394f`).
4. Now that you have a relationship in your Event Source DE linking to the EventInstanceID, you can use this to build your decision split criteria.

Comment: I confirm that this solution is working like a charm. Thank you Eliot for your time !

Comment: Good to hear! Please feel free to up vote my answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Decision Splits require a 1:1 Contact Record Relationship. Here's what I would do:

1. Create a new DE named "Event_Status" with two fields; `contactKey` and `eventStatus`. Make `contactKey` a Primary Key.
2. Link the DE you created in Step 1 to your Contact model (in Contact Builder), creating a 1:1 relationship to the Contact Record (using the `contactKey` Attribute).
3. Set the Decision Split in your Journey to use the `eventStatus` Attribute from your DE you created in Step 1.
4. Make the following request:

```json
 var options = {
        uri: '/contacts/v1/contactEvents',
        retry: true,
        form: {
   "contactKey":"A001",
   "eventDefinitionKey":"ContactEvent-XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "data":[
      {
         "name":"Website_Event",
         "items":[
            {
               "values":[
                  {}
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"Event_Status",
         "items":[
            {
               "values":[
                  {
                     "name":"contactKey",
                     "value":"A001"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"eventStatus",
                     "value":"isConnected"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
},
        json: true
    };
```

### Notes

1. You don't need to include the `id` name/value pair of the DE external key in your data array, only the `name` value of the DE is required. I've removed this, but you can include it if you really want to.
2. I'm assuming that the `eventStatus` field you created in your "Website_Event" DE is nullable, but if it is required, then you can include it in the values array (you just won't be using it).

Comment: Hi Eliot, 

Thank you so much for your time. I really appreciate it.

I tried your solution following the steps one by one but unfortunately now the data is not inserted neither in the "Website_Event" DE nor in the "Event_Status" DE and thus no contact is injected into the journey.

Were you able to insert data in a DE (that is not based on an Event template : Event_Status DE) using the route /contactEvents like you described in your solution?

Thank you so much again.

Comment: Hi @zeljazouli, sorry to hear that you are having issues. Are you sure that your `contactKey` already exists in All Contacts? If so, let's set-up a brief webinar to review, just [pick a time](https://calendly.com/eliot-harper/30min) that works for you!

Comment: Hi Eliot, yes the ContactKey exists in All Contacts ! I don't know It is not working as I followed your steps thoroughly.
I will pick a time now. Thank you again.