# Journey builder decision split doesn’t work with sfdc task

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, tasks

I am trying to evaluate a salesforce task from a journey that use has entry source opportunity - entry primary contact id.
The journey creates a task of the opportunity is > than 5k and then after one day I should check if that task has been completed if not send an email.
At the moment the contact goes through the reminder path.
The decision split checks
Contacts data > task > status = completed
Contacts data > task > subject = ends with xxxx
Opportunity Id = journey data opportunity id

I’ve added The 2/3 steps because I thought the journey will not be able to identify which task we are referring to.
I’m still not clear though because I think the problem is that it doesn’t recognise the task.
I have syncronied the sfdc task data extension before they moved into the decision split and the record shows that was completed

Comment: I had an issue like this before (different object, goal criteria) and solved it by building a query that isolated the records relevant for journey. I then tied the resulting data extension to the contact model and could it use for decision splits and goal criteria. I did it this way because data binding doesn't work for goals, yet. If you don't have to check the task status for the goal and only need it for splits you can also achieve this with data binding. This would be more efficient as you don't need additional data extensions.

Comment: However, data binding is not quite easy to understand. You should probably try to get developer support in this. This is a thread where it was used as a solution for a decision split issue and it contains a link to the documentation page: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160917/retrieve-custom-fields-linked-to-an-contactevent-in-a-decision-split?